# MySQL remote setup

Tags: networking, server, mysql, minecraft

I'll be honest I know nothing about Linux, but for a few weeks I've been setting up my Minecraft server on a virtual machine on the cloud because it's way better than hosting companies, of course you have to go through more stuff but in the long run I think it's worth it, everything was going good so far, but now I need "MySQL" or another database (I want that one because it's popular so I'll find help easily) for global ranks and to sync info across my network, I honestly have no idea what I'm doing. I can only access the machine through putty and I tried following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-EvquKadIQg) , but I have no idea how I messed up and I want to uninstall it and reinstall it clean with your help, so that I don't ruin it any more. I tried a command or something I found on Google, but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: the output in the picture means you don't have the package **mysql** or **mysql-server** in your server. so you can continue to the next step in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before begin, I think **the most important thing** you need is to clarify what the commands on ubuntu mean, so next will list a few commands that you may need to use during the mysql installation and what they mean.

Update the package database on your server

- `sudo apt-get update`

Install a package

- `sudo apt install package_name`
- e.g. install the mysql package `sudo apt install mysql-server`

lists all the packages already installed related with mysql on your system.

- `apt list --installed | grep -E 'mysql|mysql-server'`

Uninstall a package

- `sudo apt remove package_name`
- e.g. `sudo apt remove mysql-server`

If you are not sure of the package name, use this to confirm it

- `sudo apt search package_name`
- e.g. `sudo apt search mysql-server`

Comment: Thank you, you're making things easier!

Comment: If it helps you, please accept the answer and perhaps refer to [the help documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) 